# MSVC vs GCC & Clang Bug while using lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

I was trying out an example presented at [CppCon](https://youtu.be/3jCOwajNch0?t=1321) that uses **lambdas**. And to my surprise the program don't compile in gcc and clang(in either C++14 or C++17) but compiles in msvc. This can be verified [here](https://godbolt.org/z/G46bos3eW).

For reference, the example code is as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int g = 10;
auto kitten = [=]() { return g+1; };
auto cat = [g=g]() { return g+1; };

int main() {
    g = 20;
    printf("%d %d\n", kitten(), cat());
}
```

What is the problem here(if any) and which compiler is right?

Note that the code is an exact copy-paste from their official presentation slide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with MSVC. clang and g++ are correct.

From `[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/3` (C++17 draft N4659)

> A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope (6.3.3) is a local lambda expression; any
> other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer. The
> reaching scope of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost
> enclosing function and its parameters. [ Note: This reaching scope includes any intervening lambda-expressions.
> —end note ]

Since `=` is a `capture-default`, and the lambda is not within a block-scope, the code is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the problem here(if any)

Let's ask what the compilers that refuse to compile have to say:

> ```
> error: non-local lambda expression cannot have a capture-default
> ```

Let's see what the standard has to say:

> C++14 draft N4140
>
> A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope ([basic.scope.block]) is a local lambda expression; any other lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer. The reaching scope of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up to and including the innermost enclosing function and its parameters. [ Note: This reaching scope includes any intervening lambda-expressions.  — end note ]
>
> ---
>
> latest draft
>
> A lambda-expression shall not have a capture-default or simple-capture in its lambda-introducer unless its innermost enclosing scope is a block scope ([basic.scope.block]) or it appears within a default member initializer and its innermost enclosing scope is the corresponding class scope ([basic.scope.class]).

C++17 wording is nearly identical to C++14.

The program is ill-formed and the diagnostic message is correct. The compilers that don't diagnose the ill-formedness (icc, msvc) don't conform to the standard.

---

The program can be fixed simply by removing the capture-default. It cannot capture anything outside of a block scope anyway which makes it useless which is why it isn't allowed. Globals such as `::g` can be accessed without capturing them.

Comment: I wonder how they had this untested snippet in a slide at cppcon. Or maybe they tested it and the program worked and they didn't realise that it should not work and also didn't realise that it worked due to a bug.

Comment: @AnoopRana People make mistakes. Perhaps they tested their code with a compiler that failed to diagnose their bug.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant in my last comment when i said: *"they didn't realise that it should not work"*

Comment: @AnoopRana You also said "untested" though, which contradicts with that assumption :)

Comment: I think you didn't read the 2nd part of my comment which said: *"Or maybe they tested it and the program worked and they didn't realise that it should not work"*. I took into account both the situations in my first comment :)

Comment: @AnoopRana I did read it, and I provided my guess of which one is the case. Only the author themself knows for sure.

Comment: I acknowledged in my 2nd part of the comment, that my 1st part of the comment(the assumption that the code was untested) may be wrong.